# Django-Cookiecutter: Why is dist listed in .gitignore?

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

A fundamental question about the .gitignore list that's auto generated by django-cookiecutter. I suppose this it's best practice to ignore dist.

I am not a front-end/UI master but many javascript packages come with a dist folder which I just copy into the static folder. Is that a bad idea? Is there something I should know about files in a dist folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind this is that you don't commit compiled resources into git as they should be generated at deploy/build time.

Comment: Hi Jure, cheers for that! So, seems like I am lagging a bit behind in the way I include js dependencies in my projects. The first thing that comes to mind is the package.json that was generated by cookiecutter-django. I suppose I add my dependencies in there?

Comment: Yes, javascript dependencies should go in package.json and you would then use either `npm` or `yarn` to install them.